# c++ print shapes in the console (cmd)

Tags: c++

I’m building a maze game in C++ and I’m trying to use shapes to identify characters in the game i.e. walls as squares, triangles as enemies and a star shape as the player. How can I print such elements in the console `cmd`? I have been researching a lot on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but I’m not able to figure it out.

If there isn’t a way then is it possible to print an svg?

Comment: Everything is possible in C++, you just have to write the code to do it. But there are no magic buttons in C++ that only need to be pushed, to make things happen. Instead, one needs to research which algorithms, containers, libraries, or other resources are available to implement one's task, and if not how to go about doing it yourself. A console is a console because it is text only. The last time rudimentary console graphics were possible were in the days of the Commodore 64. Now, you will have to learn how to use MS-Windows APIs to draw windows. Takes about 1-3 years to learn how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, it was an extremely helpful stone-age lecture. But I’m looking for a very low level shapes printing such as https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTX30BbhIVRKTnbNhU6qCiwMix8tMT7HjjpAw&usqp=CAU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to this problem, each with its own drawbacks and advantages.

### Emoji (or more precisely Unicode)

> This is my recommendation for simple games and shapes as it is the most simple to implement and relies on the underlying console to do the heavy lifting. Also how the other program was most likely written (though with other characters than listed here)

Since the windows terminal (and linux/macOS) supports Unicode, it is possible to use unicode characters such as , ⭐, and  to represent characters.

> Note: you may need to enable utf8 support with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");` in cpp

#### Pros

1. Simple to implement
2. Doesn't rely on external libraries

#### Cons

1. Confined to the standard text alignment
2. Hard to resize
3. Need to clear characters manually
4. What happens if the console is resized or too small?

### ConPTY

Similar to the console approach, though this gives the advantage of more colors and the capability to set console size, etc. by the program.

#### Pros

1. Color support
2. Ability to control the terminal more simply

#### Cons

1. Still need to choose another method to actually print
2. Requires Windows 10

### Console

This is takes control of the console windows. You should use a library such as https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCursesMod to abstract this method.

#### Pros

1. Capable of full control without leaving the terminal
2. Less resource intensive than a full window

#### Cons

1. Complex

### Windows

You can use frameworks such as Qt and co to implement a window environment. This approach gives the most flexibility, though at the cost of complexity, with at least a couple months of development time (from scratch), though this issue can be overlooked with the proper framework/library.

#### Pros

1. More common nowadays
2. Most control
3. A number of libraries are available for games already.

#### Cons

1. Most resource intensive
2. Hardest to implement from scratch
3. Not terminal based (though you can make it seem as though it is)